# Annihilating Ideal of a Ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

I am stuck on how to show this. A starting hint would be helpful, and an answer (hidden) would be much appreciated. I tried supposing that there was another element in the annihilating ideal, however, I am not given that the ring has the cancellation property.

Prove that if $A$ is a commutative ring with unity, its annihilating ideal is equal to $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Comment: Do you mean $\text{Ann}_A (A) = 0$? In this case $xA = 0$ implies that $x 1 = 0$, hence $x = 0$

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure about that notation. I am using Pinter, and he describes the annihilating ideal of a set to be $\lbrace x \in A : ax=0  \forall a \in A\rbrace$. If these notations are the same, then yes.

Comment: In your notation you have $ax=0$ for every $a\in A$, hence $xA=0$ the zero ring.

Comment: @MrSelberg And?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Both definitions are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring with unity.

This is easiest when using the best-available definition, namely:

**Definition.** Suppose $S$ is a subset of $R$. Then to say that "$x$ is in the annihilator of $S$" is just to say that "$xS \subseteq 0$."

**Proposition.** $x$ is in the annihilator of $R$ iff $x = 0$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $xR\subseteq 0$. Then $x1 \subseteq 0$. So $x \subseteq 0$. So $x = 0$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ On the other hand, suppose $x=0$. Then $xR = 0R$. So $xR = 0$. So $xR \subseteq 0$. So $x$ is in the annihilator of $R$.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But, what is the point of the ring having unity?

Comment: @phatty, in general, or in regards to this particular problem?

Comment: In regards to the problem.

Comment: It allows us to get from $xR \subseteq 0$ to $x \subseteq 0$.

Comment: I get it. That took me a second. Thanks so much. Is the notation $Ann(A)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ equivalent notation. The person prior did not ever answer.

Comment: Yep, $\mathrm{Ann}(A) = \{0\}$ is the same as "$x \in \mathrm{Ann}(A)$ iff $x \in \{0\}$" which is the same as "$x$ is in the annihilator of $A$ iff $x = 0$."

Comment: @phatty, although it would be more precise to say: $\mathrm{Ann}(A) = \{0\}$ is the same as "for all $x \in R$, $x \in \mathrm{Ann}(A)$ iff $x=0$" which is the same as "for all $x \in R$, $x$ is in the annihilator of $A$ iff $x=0$." Mathematical convention expects people to fill in the universal quantifiers themselves, on an intuitive basis. I'm not sure if this is a good thing, see [here](http://math.andrej.com/2012/12/25/free-variables-are-not-implicitly-universally-quantified/) for some reasons why its problematic.